# CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID failure

Tags: macos, display

I am using `CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID` to get a UUID instead of a `CGDirectDisplayID` because the UUID seems to be static while the `CGDirectDisplayID` changes with the GPU.

```
-(NSString *)uuidForDisplayID:(CGDirectDisplayID)displayID
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID (displayID);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString (kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidRef);
    CFRelease (uuidRef);
    
    return ([(NSString *)string autorelease]);
}
```

This works except in the case where a screen is going away. During a `CGDisplayReconfiguration` callback, where a screen is removed, the first pass, only the `kCGDisplayBeginConfigurationFlag` is set.

At this time, calling `CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID` results in an "invalid displayID" error. However, if at the same time one gets the array of NSScreens, and searches through them with:

```
[[[screen deviceDescription] objectForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedLongValue]
```

One will find an NSScreen that matches the `CGDirectDisplayID`. Looking at the NSScreen in Xcode, there is a private ivar called `_UUIDString` that matches what `CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID` should return.

How is NSScreen getting this UUID and how can I get it when `CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID` fails because the screen is in the process of being removed?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Also, just a suggestion: what if you maintain a cache of the UUIDs of all connected monitors, and then when one is being removed, wait until NSScreen no longer returns an instance corresponding to the disconnected monitor, and then check all the UUIDs of the remaining monitors and figure out which UUID is no longer there?